# Return a single part of a date/time

Tags: mysql, database

The table down is my database(test), now I want to divide the event part into year, month, day!! I recently found out datepart doesnot work!!! Is there any other function that I can use for it!!!

```
id |       event            |     sensor                   |       MAC

649|    2014-12-18 13:40:01 |   24951484857695552516667503 |    0xDE0xAD0xBE0xEF0xFE0xED
650|    2014-12-18 13:50:38 |   24951484857695552516667503 |    0xDE0xAD0xBE0xEF0xFE0xED
```

This was example that I wanted to use

```
SELECT DATEPART(yyyy,OrderDate) AS OrderYear,
DATEPART(mm,OrderDate) AS OrderMonth,
DATEPART(dd,OrderDate) AS OrderDay
FROM Orders
WHERE OrderId=1
```

whose result would be:
will result in this:

```
OrderYear   OrderMonth  OrderDay
2008            11        11
```

Comment: MySQL does not have a `DATEPART()` function. That's why it doesn't work.

Comment: Is there any function that I can use for it!!

Comment: There are plenty of solutions out there for this. You need to research properly before you post. It is not efficient to answer the same question every time.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT year(OrderDate) AS OrderYear,
       month(OrderDate) AS OrderMonth,
       dayofmonth(OrderDate) AS OrderDay
FROM Orders
WHERE OrderId = 1
```